# Exception in thread "main" em vetor de Strings

Tags: java, array, string

Gostaria de adicionar o texto inserido pelo usuário numa posição do vetor, mas está dando erro... por que?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int cont=0;
    String inserida = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira a " +cont+ " String: "
            + "\n 0 encerra.");
    String [] vetString = null;
    while (!inserida.equals("0")) {
        cont++;
        vetString[cont] = inserida;
    }

    //linearString(vetString[], inserida);

}
```

}

Comment: provavelmente é um nullpointer, porque você está colocando vetstring = null, ao se criar um vetor ele precisa ser inicializado, ex: String[] vetString = new String[20];

Comment: Fala, Lucas, agradeço a ajuda, eu fiz isso, mas agora ele continua dando "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at blogdoprofessor.VetorDeStrings.main(VetorDeStrings.java:25)
"

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException significa que você está tentando acessar um endereço do vetor que não existe,  se por exemplo você fazer String[] vetString = new String[20] e tentar então acessar a posição 22 (vetString[22]) esse exception vai ser lançado, lembrando que arrays(não desse tipo pelo menos) não crescem dinamicamente

Comment: Imaginei que fosse exatamente isso, mas mesmo com a proposta sugerida por você, o erro persiste… mesmo para inserir a linha da posição 1 do Array, mesmo eu tendo o declarado  com tamanho 10000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código tem alguns problemas, dentre os quais:

- A condição de parada do `while` é que o valor inserido seja igual a `0`, porém o valor só é informado antes do laço. Sendo assim o laço nunca irá terminar;
- Seu `array` não é inicializado em momento algum, sendo assim, caso você tente manipulá-lo, terá a exceção `NullPointerException` lançada.

Sendo assim, ao que parece você quer inserir em todos os elementos do `array` o mesmo valor. Levando isso em conta você pode alterar seu código para o seguinte:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  final int TAMANHO = 1000;
  int cont = 0;
  String inserida = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(String.format("Insira a %s String:\n 0 encerra.", cont));
  String[] vetString = new String[TAMANHO];

  while (!inserida.equals("0") && cont < TAMANHO) {
    vetString[cont] = inserida;
    cont++;
  }

  //linearString(vetString[], inserida);
}
```